# Internet Explorer forgetting value of node

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Right off, the title for this question is not very good. If you have a suggestion on a better one, I'll be happy to change it. I also understand that this question has probably been answered before, but I lack the vocabulary to search for it.

Okay, so I have this document:

```
<p id="test-paragraph">
    There never was a <a href="">fatter</a> dog.
</p>
```

And then I have this javascript:

```
<script>
    var firstParagraph = document.getElementById('test-paragraph')
    var test = firstParagraph.firstChild;
    console.log(test);
    firstParagraph.innerHTML = '';
    console.log(test);
</script>
```

Okay, so on IE 11, the results are:

```
// "There never was a"
// EmptyTextNode
```

But the results in Chrome/Edge/Firefox are:

```
// "There never was a"
// "There never was a"
```

So, I get what's happening. IE 11 is making a pointer(?) to the first element. When that element's parent is emptied, the `firstChild` is removed and therefore the pointer goes to an empty node.

However, all modern browsers apparently make a copy of the node that is independent of the parent element.

So, questions:

1) How can I better phrase what IE 11 is doing?

2) How I can better phrase what the other browsers are doing?

3) How can I make IE 11 behave like the other browsers and copy the contents of the node, rather than point(?) to them?

4) IE 11's approach makes more sense to me (even if it is irritating). Why do modern browsers go a different way?